# Python function which needs to return a Class, returns None

Tags: python

So guys I have this class. It's a `Treasure` generator of static classes which return a `Spell` class, `Weapon` class, mana or health potion value.
The problem is, when I `return` the Value it returns `None`, but if I replace it with `print`, instead of `return`, then in prints it with no problems exactly as it in `str` function. How can I return the type, so it doesn't show me None ?

```
from random import randint
from weapon_class import Weapon
from spell_class import Spell


class Treasure:

    @staticmethod
    def generate_random_index(limit):
        rand_index = randint(0, int(limit))
        return rand_index

    @staticmethod
    def return_generated_treasure(max_mana, max_health):
        # generate num from 0-3
        rand_gen_num = Treasure.generate_random_index(3)
        options = {
            0: Treasure.generate_spell,
            1: Treasure.generate_weapon,
            2: Treasure.generate_mana_pot,
            3: Treasure.generate_health_pot
        }
        # give arguments for mana and health potion functions only (for now)
        if rand_gen_num == 2:
            options[rand_gen_num](max_mana)
        elif rand_gen_num == 3:
            options[rand_gen_num](max_health)
        else:
            # call other functions, which doesn't need arguments,
            # like generate spell and weapon
            options[rand_gen_num]()

    @staticmethod
    def generate_spell():
        with open('spell_names.txt', 'r') as f:
            database_spell_names = f.read().replace('\n', '').split(',')

        lst_len = len(database_spell_names) - 1
        # generate number in range 0 - <spell names length>
        rand_gen_num = Treasure.generate_random_index(lst_len)

        spell_name = database_spell_names[rand_gen_num]
        spell_mana_cost = randint(5, 35)
        spell_damage = randint(5, 40)
        cast_range = randint(1, 3)
        # return spell
        return Spell(spell_name, spell_damage, spell_mana_cost, cast_range)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_weapon():
        with open('weapon_names.txt', 'r') as f:
            database_weapon_names = f.read().replace('\n', '').split(',')
        lst_len = len(database_weapon_names) - 1
        rand_gen_num = Treasure.generate_random_index(lst_len)

        weapon_name = database_weapon_names[rand_gen_num]
        weapon_damage = randint(5, 40)
        # return weapon
        return Weapon(weapon_name, weapon_damage)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_mana_pot(max_mana):
        max_possible_mana_limit = max_mana * 1/2
        mana_portion = randint(0, int(max_possible_mana_limit))
        return mana_portion

    @staticmethod
    def generate_health_pot(max_health):
        max_possible_health_limit = max_health * 1/3
        health_portion = randint(0, int(max_possible_health_limit))
        return health_portion

def main():
    award = Treasure.return_generated_treasure(100, 100)
    print (award)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What's the point of having a class with only static methods? Can't you just write a module with a bunch of functions?

Comment: I'm new to Python and still don't know what modules are. Also wanted to practice static classes and functions.

Comment: Well, to make it simple, a module is a .py file. If you need just to group together some functions and/or classes because of semantic reason, you should write them in a separate module (.py file), then import it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return_generated_treasure` doesn't return anything - there's no `return` keyword there.

Comment: It's chaining through other functions, they return a result ?

Comment: It *calls* the other functions, then discards the(ir) returned value.

Comment: ohh yeah, a return in front of options did the work. Thank you !

Comment: @nKolchakoV: please accept this answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to make outputs of other functions global. As they are returned within the function, their returns become local, and are then not propagated through the class or further returned.